# Cronysm vs oligarchy

Tags: democracy, terminology

What is the difference between these two?

Which claims are true for cronyism but not for oligarchy, and vice verse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are totally independent.

**Oligarchy** simply means that the power is concentrated in the hands of the few powerful individuals. No more and no less.

Note that contrary to common usage connotation, they don't even need to be wealthy - especially when they take power, though it's hard to find an oligarchy where the oligarchs stay poor.

---

**Cronyism** is awarding parts of the power you hold (typically, political power via political post appointments; but also preferable treatment under your own power such as awarding government contracts) to people you're friendly with, over people who are best suited.

Cronyism can be present under ANY form of government, from representative democracy (Obama administration is frequently accused of this, for example see John Corzine affair, or Solyndra and other "green" investments into firms of DNC supportrers); to more authoritorian governments (Russia has been well known for this for century, from Tzarism through Socialism to yeltzin's times, to Putin's rule), to outright tyranny (Nazi Germany wasn't wholly a paragon of meritocracy).

Comment: You are not going to have this in a true democracy.  But this is very prevalent throughout the US especially at the local level.  And Nazi Germany is an example of an Oligarchy where there was concentrated power but very little Cronyism.

Comment: @Chad - true democracy is impossible. The talented demagogues in true democracy would always have more power than asocial geeks. Then they would give that power to their buddies.

Comment: I would say highly improbable.  In a true democracy there is no power to give because everything would be voted on.  Also the larger the scale the less workable a democracy is.  A few thousand people would be more feasible than a few hundred thousand which is more feasible than a few million... etc.  The demagogue's power is in their ability to persuade people to vote in a certain way.  That power is not absolute and there is no real way to delegate that power so there is no real cronyism.

Comment: @Chad - I meant they would convince the populace to vote for proposals to benefit their cronies. Agreed on non-scalability of democracy

Comment: That isnt really cronyism so much as sheeplism... a problem that exists in any free society.

Answer (score 5):

Oligarchy is rule by a powerful few. Its not inherent to the term how they became powerful or whether they make good or bad decisions.

Cronyism is a term for politicians who give wealth and power to their political supporters. These supporters can be a small group of oligarchs who in turn call the shots and rule the nation.

The supporters could also be a large group. For example, many see politicians who support unbreakable tenure and increasing wages for under performing teachers as cronies of teachers unions. Teachers union cronies, however, are not supporting oligarchs because there are a large number of teachers in society. Other large groups often labeled cronies of politicians include [realators](http://www.realtor.org/articles/senate-passes-flood-insurance-with-house-amendments) , [sailors](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merchant_Marine_Act_of_1920), bureaucrats, and farmers. All of these groups benefit from government action, but none are concentrated or powerful enough to be considered oligarchs.

Comment: Tnx, so cronies are basically small or large interest groups like syndicates? (while oligarchs are almost always a mighty few)

Comment: This is a very simplistic answer. I think this question deserves one much better and more detailed, as well as referenced.

Comment: @chad this is a very simplistic question. Given the nature of the question, I think this is actually the best answer the questioner could expect.

Comment: @Chad - I'm unsure a much more detailed answer is possible given the nature of the question, but feel free to try at a better one. Examples would definitely help.